# How to bond the laminated steel sheets to form the stack before cutting

Tags: motor, stator

I have 0.35mm laminated steel sheets, and I want to make it bond together to form the stack. What is the method that I can use?

This stack will be used to be the stator for bearingless motor in temple design. So! I need to form a stack and cut it.

Comment: This is not a question about electrical engineering per se.  If -- as I strongly suspect -- you are building a motor or a transformer, it would be a great help if you would _edit the text of your question_ to mention this.  Tags are nice for searching, but _I_ certainly missed them until my second reading of your question.

Comment: I don't know how it's done _now_, but from taking stuff apart back in the day, it looks like the plates were coated with some sort of solvent-based lacquer, then stacked, then a coat was put over the outside.  There are probably all sorts of methods depending on the mechanical needs of the device: I would expect that in a production situation the armature design would be done by a mechanical engineer in close consultation with a magnetic designer.  If you can, a visit to an electronics scrapyard should give you lots of stuff to take apart and ponder on.

Comment: I've seen bolts used

Comment: Aren't the laminations meant to be insulated from each other to limit eddy currents? -

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: They are probably glued together with epoxy or some other industrial adhesive. The outside may be powder coated or otherwise covered with something conformal to help protect the windings from sharp edges.

Comment: @mkeith Is it normally used for bond laminated steel sheets for motor stator? after do this, can I used wire-EDM machine?

Comment: My favourite machinist uses cyanoacrylate glue for these types of jobs, but I suspect a clamp and either wire edm or water jet machining would suffice. You might also try a really strong magnet.

Comment: I don't really know what is normal.

Answer (score 1):

Place flux between the plates, raise to white hot and hammer them together to weld them. Any blacksmith could do it.

Comment: This is a joke answer. Please do not take it seriously.

Comment: @mkeith No. It's a valid answer to a badly posed question.

Comment: My comment was directed to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you have *laminated* [electrical steel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_steel) sheets, and want to assemble these (permanently) as a motor stator, then cut this using a wire-EDM machine. I am assuming that *laminated* here means that the sheets are silicon-steel, and are coated with a thin insulator such [C3A or C4A+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_steel#Lamination_coatings).

This poses an EDM problem, because each of the sheets will be electrically insulated from each other, making (electrical) cutting a challenge.

If you can, use the (CNC) EDM to cut all sheets precisely to size, then assemble (no post-machining needed.)

If it must be EDM cut afterwards, what I would do:

- Make a jig to hold the assembled sheets.
- When cutting out the initial shape, leave a thin "tab" protruding at the same location on each sheet. These will be removed later.*
- Using a sander/grinder, expose the metal on the ends of the tabs.  Since this metal contains silicon, use a respirator.
- Lay first sheet into the jig.
- Lightly paint / epoxy / conformal / adhesive everywhere except the tabs.
- Assemble all sheets and lightly clamp jig.  Leave dry/cure for several days.
- Remove assembly from jig.  Using a torch / TIG welder and silicon-bronze brazing wire, join all of the tabs.  Careful not to overheat the sheets; might take several short passes.
- Now EDM to desired shape, using the weld as the electrical connection to all sheets.
- As the final EDM cut, cut off the tabs. You'll be left with small and sharp burrs; touch them with the sander / grinder.  Then apply a light coat of conformal to the entire stator (or dip it), to seal it and prevent corrosion.

* If you already have the sheets cut out (so cannot add tabs) then it may be possible to expose the edge of the metal at one location on all sheets and weld them together.  TIG would have much better control over this than torch welding.  But the weld will have to be carefully ground off after EDM cutting. If any two-or-more sheets remain electrically connected, it will degrade motor performance.

Comment: If I can cut all sheets via CNC or EDM first. I want to know that how can I assemble it permanently?